# How to deduce sub generic types from main generic type?

Tags: rust

Is it possible to change this code to specify just the main type: `impl Writer<MyTable>` and let Rust deduce the `H` and `R` parameters automatically?

```rust
trait Table<H, R> {
    fn rows(&self) -> &Vec<R>;
    fn header(&self) -> &H;
}

// MyTable implements Table

trait Writer<H, R, T: Table<H, R>> {}

impl Writer<MyTableHeader, MyTableRow, MyTable> for WriterImpl {}
```

Comment: On an aside note, consider returning `&[R]` instead of `&Vec<R>`. The caller will be no worse off because they couldn't mutate the vector through a shared reference to begin with, and using a slice avoids hard-coding how the data is stored in the table (other than it being stored contiguously). Also, a slice has one less level of indirection when accessing the data because it contains the pointer to data, whereas a reference to the vector first has to access the vector, and only then the data.

Comment: ^ That comment in more detail: [Why is it discouraged to accept a reference to a String (&String), Vec (&Vec), or Box (&Box) as a function argument?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40006219/155423)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to solve your problem would be to move the `H` and `R` template parameters into the `Table` trait as associated types:

```rust
trait Table {
    type Header;
    type Row;

    fn rows(&self) -> &Vec<Self::Row>;
    fn header(&self) -> &Self::Header;
}
```

When implementing this trait, you specify which type to use as `Header` and `Row`.

You can then modify your `Writer` to accept only one template parameter:

```rust
trait Writer<T: Table> {}
```